# passing pointer argument to std::vector function

Tags: c++

I have a C++ application (let's call it "client") that does extensive use of double pointers to store and pass arrays among its functions and across several dlls.

I need to integrate that with a C++ library that instead exposes function arguments as std::vector.
I am well aware that the "cleanest" answer would be to rewrite the client to replace pointers with vectors, but that is not an option at the moment.

For instance, this is one of the functions provided by the library:

```
EXPORT void* swt(vector<double> &, int , string , vector<double> &, int &);
```

and this is one of the double pointers I need to pass as first argument to the function above:

```
double* TSF_MAD = (double*)malloc(DatasetsCount*sizeof(double));
```

I have tried both the following, but both raise the same error (C2664):

```
swt(TS, TSLen, "Test", TS, d);
swt(&TS[0], TSLen, "Test", &TS[0], d);
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do not just add tags because a letter matches! C and C++ are different languages!

Comment: Oh no, not `malloc`.

Comment: use `new` operator in c++ instead of `malloc`

Comment: The majority of this code is distinctly C++, and porting it to C could take quite a bit of effort, so the C tag is inappropriate. Using `malloc` in C++ is probably a result of poor judgement. Would you mind explaining what the error says?

Comment: @Olaf, I included the C tag because it IS relevant to my question! Pointers are the  the most common way to handle arrays in C, so I see this as an interoperability question between the two languages.

Comment: @ViktorSimkó, as clearly stated in my question, rewriting the client is NOT an option at the moment.

Comment: @Seb: the error message says "a reference of type "std:vector<double, std::allocator<double> > &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "double*"

Comment: To state again: You do not have an interop problem between C and C++. **Both** parts are C++! Just because you use pointers does not rectify adding irrelevant tags. Otherwise you could also add Modula and tags for other languages which have pointers! Please take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: How about writing a conversion function that takes an array and returns a vector? Then you can write `std::vector<double> vec = ArrayToVector(TS); swt(vec, vec.size(), "Test", vec, d);`

Comment: @Olaf I did not say I **have** an interop problem. I said this question **can be relevant** for interop problems.

Comment: This question can *not* be relevant for interop problems, because a C program cannot directly call a C++ function that has `vector` parameters.

Comment: You're trying to pass a pointer to double as a parameter to a function that accepts a reference to a `std::vector<double>`. There is no automatic conversion between the two. You need to either write a conversion function or better, use only `std::vector`s

Comment: @CompuChip I could do that. I was trying to avoid to re-invent the wheel, hence my question

Comment: @gcaglion & BlackDwarf & CompuChip no need to write a conversion function, since `std::vector` already has a constructor accepting two iterators (and pointers conform to the requirements of an iterator). See my answer.

Comment: @gcaglion Do you understand what the error means? If not, why not ask a question about that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a pointer to a function that expects a vector. You need to pass a vector. If you do have a pointer to an array of objects, then you can copy the data into a vector, and then pass that vector to the function.

```
auto v = std::vector<double>(TSF_MAD, TSF_MAD + DatasetsCount);
```

The library would be better implemented by accepting templated iterators, so that you could use any data structure such as a raw array, vector, or a set. Just like the algorithms from the standard library. It would also allow passing partial ranges inside a vector, rather than entire container. If you can modify the library, then I suggest that you do this.